# Find all rows where there is another row which has in same field value from to-be-found-row +1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, window-functions

I have the following table (irrelevant fields and rows emitted for clarity):

```
customerID        MediaIDdec
--------------    ----------------------
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
16253             453456691
36178             453456692
24352             671254112
81432             226124312
44513             226124313
31336             226124314
64231             453653811
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
```

The query should return all rows (row1) where MediaIDdec within another row (row2) is MediaIDdec (Row1) + 1 .

From the above example table, this would return:

```
16253             453456691     (because there is MediaIDdec+1 within row with customerID 36178)
81432             226124312     (because there is MediaIDdec+1 within row with customerID 44513)
44513             226124313     (because there is MediaIDdec+1 within row with customerID 31336)
```

My SQL skills are honestly not sufficient to solve such a query.

**Hint:** The table is sorted after MediaIDdec.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint, try `lead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.MediaIDdec = t.MediaIDdec + 1)
```

If `MediaIDdec` has no duplicates, an alternative is `lead()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(MediaIDdec) over(order by MediaIDdec) leadMediaIDdec 
    from mytable t
) t
where leadMediaIDdec = MediaIDdec + 1
```

Comment: the "lead" solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the ultra-fast answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case you find a `join` based solution easier to digest

```
select t1.*
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.MediaIDdec = t1.MediaIDdec + 1
```

Comment: Thanks. although I didn't try it (because I already could use GMB's answer successfully), your answer makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This approaches uses the LEAD function

```
with lead_cte as (
    select *, lead(MediaIDdec) over (order by MediaIDdec)-MediaIDdec MediaIDdec_lead_diff
    from tTable)
select *
from lead_cte
where MediaIDdec_lead_diff=1;
```